# C#: How to view the data that is being sent on a parallel port?

Tags: c#, parallel-port

I need to be able to read what signals are being *sent* on a parallel port. I guess you could consider this sniffing. The folks I am working with no longer have the ability to change an old application so they want to monitor the parallel port and log whatever is being sent on it. Can you suggest any C#.NET resources?

Comment: http://sandeep-aparajit.blogspot.com/2008/08/io-how-to-program-readwrite-parallel.html. Try this tutorial.

Comment: @Doug Did you happen to get a solution to your query?